# Autofilter sorting crashes excel,which is created by using C# with Open xml excel

Tags: c#, xml, excel

Using C# with openxml,I have generated excel document with some data,I added autofilter option in that excel using below code,

```
        string reference= "B6:BA6";
        AutoFilter autoFilter1 = new AutoFilter() { Reference = reference };

        Worksheet sheet1 = new Worksheet();
        sheet1.Append(sheetData);
        sheet1.Append(autoFilter1);
```

Filter working fine,I tried to sort the data using that autofilter option in newly created Excel,but it crashes the entire excel,It displays error message like 'Excel stopped working'...

Comment: Curious to see if a solution to this issue has been found.

Answer (score 3):

It seems Excel declares a "definedName" in workbook.xml for the sorting to work.

The one Excel generates looks like this:

```
...
</sheets>
<definedNames>
    <definedName name="_xlnm._FilterDatabase" localSheetId="0" hidden="1">Sheet1!$D$7:$G$7</definedName>
</definedNames>
...
```

Using the Open XML Sdk to mimic this behaviour seems to do the trick:

```
...
worksheet.Append(new AutoFilter {Reference = "B6:BA6"});

var definedNames = new DefinedNames();
var definedName = new DefinedName
{
    Text = "YourSheetName!$B$6:$BA$6",
    Name = "_xlnm._FilterDatabase",
    LocalSheetId = 0,
    Hidden = true,
};
definedNames.Append(definedName);
spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Append(definedNames);
...
```